# Java Swing running multiple simulations in a loop

Tags: java, swing

I have coded up a simple simulation where 2 balls moving at different speeds try to move to the middle of the frame and then move back to their starting positions. At the end a specified, `totalTime`, I end the simulation and I record this data.

My question is, is it possible to loop through and run multiple simulations automatically? Currently, when my `totalTime` is up, the animation just freezes but the window doesn't close. Ideally I guess, I'd like to see the old window close and a new window pop up with new speeds for the different balls.

So my code looks something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            double rSpeed = 0;
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            Rectangle r = frame.getBounds();
            frame.add(new MoveAgents(r.getWidth(), rSpeed));
        }            
    });
}

public MoveAgents(double w, double rFrameSpeed) {
     //initialize my 2 balls and their speeds and starting locations

    Timer timer = new Timer(15, null);
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            totalTime++;

            if (totalTime == 1000) {
                timer.stop();

                try {
                    generateCsvFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
          //otherwise, do things 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to loop through and run multiple simulations automatically?

Yes. When the simulation ends, don't try to *replace* the view. Instead,

- Invoke `stop()` on the `Timer`.
- Invoke `generateCsvFile()` to save the results.
- Initialize the simulation's model exactly as done the first time.
- Invoke `restart()` on the `Timer`.

In the example below, the model is an `int` named `data`, which the simulation simply renders and increments to `1000`. A `count` of the number of times to repeat the simulation is passed as a parameter to the `Simulation` constructor. Instead of `frame.setSize()`, override the drawing panel's `getPreferredSize()` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293513/230513
 */
public class SimTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("SimTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new Simulation(8));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class Simulation extends JPanel {

        private final Font font = this.getFont().deriveFont(36f);
        private int count;
        private int data;
        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
                if ((data += 100) == 1000) {
                    t.stop();
                    System.out.println("Saving results…");//generateCsvFile();
                    if (--count == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Fin!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        init();
                        t.restart();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        public Simulation(int count) {
            this.count = count;
            init();
            t.start();
        }

        private void init() {
            data = 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(data), 8, g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(256, 128);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SimTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks  amazing! This is infinitely better than all the problems I ran into trying to do the loop in my main method.

Comment: @Kevin: I found it helpful to think of `javax.swing.Timer` as providing a loop that can be controlled externally and doesn't block the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).